# What is the use of AudioPresentation class in Android?

Tags: java, android, mediaextractor

Recently i found that
`MediaExtractor` class has a method called `getAudioPresentations`
What does this method is for?

> The AudioPresentation class encapsulates the information that describes an audio presentation
>     which is available in next generation audio content.

I'm not able to understand this definition. Can someone please help me with it

Answer (score 0):

A list of available audio presentations in a media source can be queried using MediaExtractor.getAudioPresentations(int) . This list can be presented to a user for selection. Also Applications that parse media streams and extract presentation information on their own can create instances of AudioPresentation by using  AudioPresentation.Builder class. This AudioPresentation class is helpful specially in Audio/Video editing functionality.

For further information about the class, please refer https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/AudioPresentation.java